# Reading Input file and writing to output file one section at a time, skipping lines in getline()

Tags: c++, data-structures, file-io

I'm very new to C++ and am having difficulty with the getline() command skipping the lines from the input file and am unsure what my issue is.
The goal of the program is to read in an input file one "section" at a time, put it into a structure, and then output that line to the file, and continue until there aren't any more lines in the file.

The input files look like this:

```
000.000.0000 
lastname
street
city
state 
zipcode
firstname
000.000.0000
lastname
street
....
```

etc...
when I run the program, it outputs to the out file, but it skips and lines and continues to repeat those same lines until I forcibly stop the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

struct Person
{
      string firstName;
      string lastName;
      string phoneNumber;
};
struct Address
{
        string streetNum_Name;
        string city;
        string state;
        int zip_code;
};
struct Info
{
       Person person;
       Address address;
};

void printFileHeader(ofstream& outFile);
bool openInputFile(ifstream& inFile);
void openOutputFile(ofstream& outFile);
struct Info readInfo(ifstream& inFile, Info&);
void printInfo(ofstream& outFile, Info&);

int main()
{       
        ifstream inFile;
        ofstream outFile;
        bool fileStreamState;

        Info person;

        printFileHeader(outFile);
        fileStreamState = openInputFile(inFile);
        openOutputFile(outFile);

        cout << "Processing information. Please Wait...." << endl << endl;

        while (fileStreamState) {

        readInfo(inFile, person);
        printInfo(outFile, person);

        }

        outFile << setw(7) << "-----" << setw(20) << "---------" << setw(15) << "----------" << setw(20) << "----" 
                << setw(12) << "------------" << endl;

        cout << "Program has finished execution." << endl;
        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();
}

void printFileHeader(ofstream& outFile) {

        outFile << left << setw(7) << "Entry" << setw(20) << "Last Name" << setw(15) << "First Name" << setw(20) << "City" 
                << setw(12) << "Phone Number" << endl;
        outFile << setw(7) << "-----" << setw(20) << "---------" << setw(15) << "----------" << setw(20) << "----" 
                << setw(12) << "------------" << endl;
}

bool openInputFile(ifstream& inFile) {

        string filename;

        cout << "Enter the name of the input file: "; 
        cin >> filename;
        cout << filename << endl << endl;

        inFile.open(filename.c_str());

        while(inFile.fail()) {
                
                cout << string(15,'*') << " File Open Error " <<  string(15,'*')  << endl;
                cout << "==> Input file failed to open properly!!\n";
                cout << "==> Attempted to open file: " << filename << endl;
                cout << "==> Try Again\n";
                cout << string(47,'*') << endl<< endl;

                inFile.clear();

                cout << "Enter in the name of the input file: ";
                cin >> filename;
                cout << filename << endl << endl;  
                inFile.open(filename.c_str());  
        }
        return 1;
}

void openOutputFile(ofstream& outFile) {

        string filename;

        cout << "Enter the name of the output file: ";
        cin >> filename;
        cout << filename << endl << endl;

        outFile.open(filename.c_str());

        while(outFile.fail()) {

                cout << string(15,'*') << " File Open Error " <<  string(15,'*')  << endl;
                cout << "==> Output file failed to open properly!!\n";
                cout << "==> Attempted to open file: " << filename << endl;
                cout << "==> Try Again\n";
                cout << string(47,'*') << endl<< endl;

                outFile.clear();

                cout << "Enter in the name of the input file: ";
                cin >> filename;
                cout << filename << endl << endl;  
                outFile.open(filename.c_str());  
        }
}

struct Info readInfo(ifstream& inFile, Info& record) {

        getline(inFile, record.person.phoneNumber);
        cout << record.person.phoneNumber << endl;

        inFile.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        getline(inFile, record.person.lastName);
        cout << record.person.lastName << endl;

        inFile.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        getline(inFile, record.address.streetNum_Name); 
        cout << record.address.streetNum_Name << endl;

        inFile.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        getline(inFile, record.address.city);
        cout << record.address.city << endl;

        inFile.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        getline(inFile, record.address.state); 
        cout << record.address.state << endl;

        inFile.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        inFile >> record.address.zip_code;
        cout << record.address.zip_code << endl;

        inFile.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        getline(inFile, record.person.firstName);
        cout << record.person.firstName << endl;

        return record;
}

void printInfo(ofstream& outFile, Info& record) {

        static int entry = 0;

        entry++;

        outFile << left << setw(7) << entry << setw(20) << record.person.lastName << setw(15) << record.person.firstName 
                << setw(20) << record.address.city << setw(12) << record.person.phoneNumber << endl;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are `ignore()`'ing data in `readInfo()` that you should not be ignoring. `getline()` reads everything up to *and including* a line break, and then discards the line break. So you are reading the `phoneNum` data, then `ignore()`'ing the `lastName` data, then reading the `streetNum` data, then `ignore()`'ing the `city` data, etc. You need to remove all of the `ignore()`'s after `getline()`'s, the only `ignore()` you need is the one after reading the `zip_code` with `operator>>`:

```cpp
struct Info readInfo(ifstream& inFile, Info& record) {

        getline(inFile, record.person.phoneNumber);
        cout << record.person.phoneNumber << endl;

        getline(inFile, record.person.lastName);
        cout << record.person.lastName << endl;

        getline(inFile, record.address.streetNum_Name); 
        cout << record.address.streetNum_Name << endl;

        getline(inFile, record.address.city);
        cout << record.address.city << endl;

        getline(inFile, record.address.state); 
        cout << record.address.state << endl;

        inFile >> record.address.zip_code;
        inFile.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << record.address.zip_code << endl;

        getline(inFile, record.person.firstName);
        cout << record.person.firstName << endl;

        return record;
}
```

That being said, your `while` loop in `main()` is broken. Once `readInfo()` reads the last record in the file, if the last `firstName` ends with a line break then EOF hasn't been reached yet, so `while (fileStreamState)` will still evaluate as true and the loop will call `readInfo()` and `printInfo()` again, even though there is no more record data left to read/print.

There is no good reason to have `readInfo()` take the `struct` as a reference and also return it. So you should return a `bool` instead indicating success/fail:

```cpp
bool readInfo(ifstream& inFile, Info&);

...

while (readInfo(inFile, person)) {
    printInfo(outFile, person);
}

...

bool readInfo(ifstream& inFile, Info& record) {

        getline(inFile, record.person.phoneNumber);
        cout << record.person.phoneNumber << endl;

        getline(inFile, record.person.lastName);
        cout << record.person.lastName << endl;

        getline(inFile, record.address.streetNum_Name); 
        cout << record.address.streetNum_Name << endl;

        getline(inFile, record.address.city);
        cout << record.address.city << endl;

        getline(inFile, record.address.state); 
        cout << record.address.state << endl;

        inFile >> record.address.zip_code;
        inFile.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << record.address.zip_code << endl;

        getline(inFile, record.person.firstName);
        cout << record.person.firstName << endl;

        return !inFile.fail();
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/gkMRI7)

Comment: One of the issues I had is that a requirement for the program was to make the function readInfo return the structure holding the values read back to main(). I'm assuming I should pass it as value instead of reference?

Comment: @oRedNCS the function can "return" the struct to `main()` just fine, using EITHER the function's return value OR a reference parameter. It SHOULD NOT use both, that is just redundant. But you need a way to indicate to `main()` when a struct can't be read, so a reference parameter makes more sense so you can have a `bool` return value. Or vice versa, but that is not as clean.

Comment: So I changed the function to a bool returning function using the structure as a reference parameter but the firstname is being ignored still in the file and it cycles once before it ends prematurely

Comment: @oRedNCS sorry, my bad. One of the `ignore()`'s is actually needed. I have updated my examples to put it back in. I have provided a working demo now. However, in the file data you provided, `zipcode` will not read into an `int` using `operator>>`, which was throwing off the code logic, so I had to account for that in my demo, too.

Answer (score 0):

The **complete working program** given [below](https://onlinegdb.com/bnr9UN_oS) shows how you can achieve what you want. I have done some corrections to your given code snippet. Major changes include using a `std::vector` for storing information and also calling `readInfo()` and `printInfo()` only once instead of calling them again and again in a while loop. Using a vector has the advantage that you can use that vector for later purposes(if any).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Person
{
      string firstName ;
      string lastName;
      string phoneNumber;
};
struct Address
{
        string streetNum_Name;
        string city;
        string state;
        int zip_code = 70; //always initialize built in type in block/local scope
};
struct Info
{
       Person person;
       Address address;
};

void printFileHeader(ofstream& outFile);
bool openInputFile(ifstream& inFile);
void openOutputFile(ofstream& outFile);
void readInfo(ifstream& inFile, std::vector<Info>&);
void printInfo(ofstream& outFile, std::vector<Info>&);

int main()
{       
        ifstream inFile;
        ofstream outFile;
        bool fileStreamState;

        std::vector<Info> infoVec; //this vector will contain all the information
        
        //Info person; //no need for this anymore since we have the vector

        //printFileHeader(outFile);//call this after openOutputFile() 
        fileStreamState = openInputFile(inFile);
        openOutputFile(outFile);
        printFileHeader(outFile);
        cout << "Processing information. Please Wait...." << endl << endl;

        readInfo(inFile, infoVec) ; //call readInfo once instead of calling again and again
        printInfo(outFile, infoVec);//call printInfo once instead of calling again and again
        
        

        outFile << setw(7) << "-----" << setw(20) << "---------" << setw(15) << "----------" << setw(20) << "----" 
                << setw(12) << "------------" << endl;

        cout << "Program has finished execution." << endl;
        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();
}

void printFileHeader(ofstream& outFile) {

        outFile << left << setw(7) << "Entry" << setw(20) << "Last Name" << setw(15) << "First Name" << setw(20) << "City" 
                << setw(12) << "Phone Number" << endl;
        outFile << setw(7) << "-----" << setw(20) << "---------" << setw(15) << "----------" << setw(20) << "----" 
                << setw(12) << "------------" << endl;
}

bool openInputFile(ifstream& inFile) {

        string filename;

        cout << "Enter the name of the input file: "; 
        cin >> filename;
        cout << filename << endl << endl;

        inFile.open(filename.c_str());

        while(inFile.fail()) {
                
                cout << string(15,'*') << " File Open Error " <<  string(15,'*')  << endl;
                cout << "==> Input file failed to open properly!!\n";
                cout << "==> Attempted to open file: " << filename << endl;
                cout << "==> Try Again\n";
                cout << string(47,'*') << endl<< endl;

                inFile.clear();

                cout << "Enter in the name of the input file: ";
                cin >> filename;
                cout << filename << endl << endl;  
                inFile.open(filename.c_str());  
        }
        return 1;
}

void openOutputFile(ofstream& outFile) {

        string filename;

        cout << "Enter the name of the output file: ";
        cin >> filename;
        cout << filename << endl << endl;

        outFile.open(filename.c_str());

        while(outFile.fail()) {

                cout << string(15,'*') << " File Open Error " <<  string(15,'*')  << endl;
                cout << "==> Output file failed to open properly!!\n";
                cout << "==> Attempted to open file: " << filename << endl;
                cout << "==> Try Again\n";
                cout << string(47,'*') << endl<< endl;

                outFile.clear();

                cout << "Enter in the name of the input file: ";
                cin >> filename;
                cout << filename << endl << endl;  
                outFile.open(filename.c_str());  
        }
}

void readInfo(ifstream& inFile, std::vector<Info> &infoVec) {
        std::string temporaryZipCode;
        Info info;
        while(getline(inFile, info.person.phoneNumber,'\n'),
        getline(inFile, info.person.lastName,'\n'),
        getline(inFile, info.address.streetNum_Name,'\n'),
        getline(inFile, info.address.city,'\n'),
        getline(inFile, info.address.state,'\n'),
        getline(inFile, temporaryZipCode, '\n'),
        getline(inFile, info.person.firstName,'\n')
        )
        {
            
            
            
            std::istringstream ss(temporaryZipCode);
            ss >> info.address.zip_code;
            
            infoVec.emplace_back(info);
            
           
           
        }
        

        
}

void printInfo(ofstream& outFile, std::vector<Info> &infoVec) {

        int entry = 0; //no need for making it static 

        
        for(const Info& record: infoVec )
        {
            
            outFile << left << setw(7) << entry << setw(20) << record.person.lastName << setw(15) << record.person.firstName 
                << setw(20) << record.address.city << setw(12) << record.person.phoneNumber << endl;
                entry++;
        }
        
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/bnr9UN_oS). I have added comments wherever i have made changes to your program.